# Is there a technical term for the process of a dialectal word being accepted as part of the standard variety?

Tags: terminology, dialects

For example, the word *pet* appeared originally in [Scottish and northern England dialect](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pet#etymonline_v_12783), but it is no longer felt as specific to certain regions. I have not discovered any appropriate term for such phenomenon.

By the way, is there a technical term for the reverse process (i.e. the process of generally accepted words being reckoned as dialectal terms)? An example is that the archaic word *emmet* is chiefly viewed as dialectal.

Comment: _Pet_ is still very clearly dialectal to Northern England (not even Scotland, I think?) in its use as a term of endearment for women and children. But not, of course, in the more general use relating to tamed animals kept for pleasure.

Comment: What do you mean by a dialectal word becoming standard? Linguistically, English has tons of dialects. Words are said to be lexicalized. https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.1086/683179 Great article. As with all English words, it depends on the institution or source you are looking at. There is no agreement about an issue like this.

Comment: this seems to be a matrer of socio-linguistica to some extent, because the particular pathway matters. For example, if a seizable population of bilunguals makes frequent use of code switching, it should be difficult to say that they borrowed the word ... from themselves. And the category of such mixed languages is definitely a socio-linguistic matter in the most common case

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing. The standard variety borrows the word from a dialect.

Comment: That’s one description of it, not a name for the phenomenon as such. Borrowing, obviously, is much broader than just a standard variety borrowing a word from a dialect. Indeed, in some cases ‘borrowing’ may not even be an accurate description. It’s entirely possible to take in a word from another dialect without realising it’s not part of your own – it would be a stretch to call that a borrowing as such. E.g., [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/180271) just taught me the word _bassinet_, which I’d never heard before – did I ‘borrow’ it? Does it matter if it’s dialectal?

Comment: There are so many lexical items in any language, each with their own history and provenance, that there's no special term for any of the thousands of forms it may have taken for one kind of borrowing. They all come from somewhere, and what other lects the person you heard it from habitually spoke  is just unavailable --hence indescribable -- information

Comment: A more general term is [**lexicalization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicalization).